# TileMill raster-colorizer

Tags: raster, tilemill

I am trying to use the raster-colorizer in Tilemill (v0.10.1) but it is giving me an error.
I did set in the advanced section the band to `band="1"`. What else do I have to do in order to use raster-colorizer?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't confirm that, but I think this feature is only available on the Tilemill development version ( v0.10.2 ).

You can get more information here: 
https://www.mapbox.com/blog/tilemill-raster-colorizer/

If you need to install the development version, I recommend looking into this guide:
https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/source/

Cheers

Comment: You are right. It says: "This works in the development version of TileMill..."

Comment: Hi, can you provide me the URL for that version. I am also unable to find that now.